# Paste Range of formula Cells not changing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a range of formula into a specific row.

But the formula cells doesn't change:

```
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A13;A13)
```

`A13` is supposed to change while pasting :

[image]

On this screen example the cells formula should be  :

```
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A23;A23)
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A24;A24)
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A25;A25)
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A26;A26)
=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A27;A27)
```

And so on.. But cells does not change

Below is my code :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim AJD As Date
Dim LastDate As Date

Application.Calculation = xlManual

AJD = Now

AJD = Day(AJD) & "/" & Month(AJD) & "/" & Year(AJD)

If AJD <> CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Histo").Range("A13").Value) Then



    LastDate = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Histo").Range("A13").Value)
    NumberOfIt = DateDiff("D", LastDate, AJD)
    
    MsgBox ("MaJ Historique, Derniere Mise a jour : " & LastDate & " Insertion de " & NumberOfIt & " nouvelles lignes")
    
    DoEvents
    For i = 1 To NumberOfIt - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Histo").Rows(13).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Histo").Range("A13").Value = DateAdd("d", i, LastDate)
         With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Histo")
            lrow = NumberOfIt
            .Range("B13:DM13").Formula = .Range("B5:DM5").Formula
        End With
    Next


End If
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Primary Pricer").Activate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
MsgBox ("Historique MaJ terminé")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

When I insert a New Row how can I update formula in order to change the cells ?

For example I insert a `Row(13)` So the formula below should be `=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A14;A14)` and not `=BDH('Hist Dorian'!$B$3;"PX_LAST";A13;A13)` but it does not change as excepted

**Edit 2**

```
Sub pasteFormulas()
    Range("F6").Copy
    Range("G6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Rows(6).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.Range("B13:DM13").Copy 
.Range("B5:DM5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

in the for loop.

Below the sample code I tried that works for a cell:

```
Sub pasteFormulas()
    Range("F6").Copy
    Range("G6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        'SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Error Compil : Excepted; end of statement at `Paste`

Comment: try only .Range("B13:DM13").Copy = .Range("B5:DM5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

Comment: sorry, I edited the answer. Is the copy statement, and then the paste. No = as I posted before

Comment: Is it working for you ? Cells are not being updated

Comment: When I add new row formula does not change

Comment: I tried it out for a cell and its working. Find the trial code in the updated answer

Comment: Can you see my edit ? You got to insert a row after to see if the formula are being updated

Comment: I added the code to try at the end of my post are the cells changed on insert ?

Comment: the formulas below maintain their original row number, they do not do +1 automatically because yo added a row. If you want your below cell formulas row index updated you should paste the formulas in all the range below the row inserted

Comment: Thank you Thats what I needed to know